# Get working day of the month with the lowest value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel spreadsheet with two columns. One with a date and another with the value.

I want to get the working day of the month with the lowest value.

I tried to use a pivot table for it and then group the date but I get a lot of errors.

You can find the spreadsheet here and the sheet name is Historical. The others are just attempts made by me.

[Spreadsheet](https://easyupload.io/6w21xv)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The formula entered in `E2` below
[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formulae]
is

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(POWER(10,LOG10(((YEAR(D2)=YEAR($A$2:$A$3254))*(MONTH(D2)=MONTH($A$2:$A$3254)))))*$B$2:$B$3254),1)
```

and the [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) entered in `F2` below is

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$3254,MATCH(YEAR(D2)&MONTH(D2)&E2,YEAR($A$2:$A$3254)&MONTH($A$2:$A$3254)&$B$2:$B$3254,0))
```

Comment: How is the D column (Month) generated?

Comment: @kylie.zoltan `D2` just contains 1-May-2022, `D3` contains the formula `=EDATE(D2,-1)` which is copied down - the entire column is custom-number formatted as `mmm-yy`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to make an triple nested if-construct that checks if the weekday of the date is a workday, or the date+ 1 or the day +2. Assuming the date is in cell A4

```
= if(instr(weekday(A4),”23456”)>0, A4, 
if(instr(weekday(A4+1),”23456”)>0, A4 + 1, 
if(instr(weekday(A4+2),”23456”)>0, A4 + 2,”cannot happen”)))
```

Explanation: one of 3 consecutive days is always a working day.
There may be typos since I edit that on iPad without Excel available to test.
Weekday returns 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday. So 2-6 are workdays.

However with that simple approach you will not detect public holidays on a working day if that is a problem.

Hope I understood you question correctly. One data example with solution would have explained it better.